# Parsing texts from XML file with QXmlStreamReader, '\n' replaced with '\\n'

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

I am parsing a xml file with QXmlStreamReader.
This XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LangDef langCode="0809">
    <LangID ID="0x0100" Text="Foo"/>
    <LangID ID="0x0101" Text="Foo \n Bar."/>
</LangDef>
```

The problem I have is that, when doing

```
text = attribute.value().toString().toStdString();
```

the value of text results in `"Foo \\n Bar."`. What should I do to make it write `"Foo \n Bar."`?

Comment: how are you viewing the value of `text`? In the debugger? Many debug visualisers escape slashes in strings for you

Comment: FYI: `<LangID ID="0x0101" Text="Foo \n Bar."/>` '`\n`' doesn't encode a newline in the value of the XML attribute `Text`. Instead, it encodes a backslash and an `n` literally. (A newline in XML could be encoded e.g. with `&#10;` or `&#xa;`.)

Comment: If really have these as newlines, you will have to do `text.replace("\\n", "\n")`

Comment: I ended up doing as @FrankOsterfeld said. I can't edit the texts (I could, but it's a lot of them and they are provided by the customer so if they edit it I should re-edit them again) and that are new lines characters indeed. I hoped there were some cleaner way, something like saying to QString not to manipulate those characters, but at the end it was easier to replace \\n with \n

Comment: "saying to QString not to manipulate those characters," - QString doesn't manipulate anything here, it's just that `\n` has no special meaning in XML, only in C/C++ string literals it does mean "newline".